# KeyPress malfunction in applet

Tags: java, applet, awt, keypress, keylistener

Below is the applet I've been making which allows the user to move a rectangle across the screen with the arrow keys. All the keys work except for the down key, which make the rectangle move down-right in a diagonal line. The answer is probably obvious; hopefully not! Please help! Thank you!

```
import javax.swing.*;

import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class Move extends Applet implements KeyListener {
    private Rectangle rect;
    private ArrayList<Integer> keysDown;

public void init() {
    this.addKeyListener(this);
    keysDown = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, 50, 50);
}

public void paint(Graphics g) {
    setSize(600, 400);
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;
    g2.fill(rect);
}

@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    if (!keysDown.contains(e.getKeyCode()))
        keysDown.add(new Integer(e.getKeyCode()));
moveRect();
}

@Override
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
    keysDown.remove(new Integer(e.getKeyCode()));
}

public void moveRect() {
    int x = rect.x;
    int y = rect.y;
    if (keysDown.contains(KeyEvent.VK_UP)) {
        y -= 2;
    }
    if (keysDown.contains(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN)) {
        y += 2;
    }
    if (keysDown.contains(KeyEvent.VK_LEFT)) {
        x -= 2;
    }
    if (keysDown.contains(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN)) {
        x += 2;
    }
    rect.setLocation(x, y);
    repaint();
}

@Override
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {

}
}
```

Comment: 1) +1 for posting an SSCCE.  Glad you got it sorted.  :)  2) There is no need to add the major tag in the title of the question.  ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you missing a `VK_RIGHT` in the if statements in `moveRect` where you handle keypresses?

I see you have two `VK_DOWN` - this will move the rectangle along both X and Y when you press the down-key.

Look through these lines in the `moveRect` method and note how `VK_DOWN` is handled twice, (and that `VK_RIGHT` isn't handled at all):

```
if (keysDown.contains(KeyEvent.VK_UP)) {
    y -= 2;
}
if (keysDown.contains(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN)) {
    y += 2;
}
if (keysDown.contains(KeyEvent.VK_LEFT)) {
    x -= 2;
}
if (keysDown.contains(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN)) {
    x += 2;
}
```

Comment: Could you highlight the troublesome code block, took me a minute of staring to pick it up +1

Comment: That must be it! Sorry for the inconvenience. I even looked at the code...+1!